# image not rendering in ie6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have a small riddle here: one html page has a comment before img declaration, like this:

```
<!---->
<img src='shar.gif' alt='' class='center'/>
```

and another has not:

```
<img src='shar.gif' alt='' class='center'/>
```

Former image is rendered in ie6, while latter is not. Both pages are declared as XHTML 1.0 Transitional, and w3c validator says OK both for html and css for both pages. Opera, Firefox, Safari render image in both cases. Even ie 7.0 and ie 8.0 render the same.

Here is a small local version of [robust sample](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/458861/working.zip).
And here is a [failure one](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/458861/notworking.zip). Any ideas why (empty or not) comment before an image makes it 'visible' in ie?

Comment: Hello.
Your links require some Russian Picasa login.

Comment: Please change the links to somewhere that doesn't require a login.

Comment: Sorry for that. Broken links are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>img</title>
        <meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!---->
    <img src='smaller.jpg' alt='' class='center'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Works well for me in FF 3 and IE 6.
Maybe it has to do with the CSS?
Please post a wider sample...

Comment: Links are at the bottom of the question post. Thanks.

Comment: please see Kobi's comment on question post - no access without Russian Picasa login

Comment: Sorry for that. Broken links are fixed. It's all about an app in development.